# Per particle displacement with displacment node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, displacement

I am trying to make a displacement for each particle, using a displacement node (so not a displacement modifier!).

[image]

But they all share the displacement.

[image]

Is there anyway to make the displacement happen on a per particle basis?

And if not, what is the right place to request this future?

Comment: Do you think you can connect the Particle Info ... function of [Index] ... to some function  of input to the displacement ?

Comment: No, they will all displace the same. Only if I make instances from each particle, then I can get it to work. But this has a huge influence on performance.

Comment: Please show your most recent work as a Blender screen capture.